# Does chaining sort and reduce increase time complexity from O(n) to O(n ^ 2)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time

In terms of time complexity, is this:

```
let string = "I am a little teapot"
let wordArray = string.split(' ').sort()
let store = wordArray.reduce( (acc, word) => {
       acc[word] = acc[word] + 1 || 1;
       return acc;
     }, {})
```

any better than this? :

```
let string = "I am a little teapot"
let store = string.split(' ').sort().reduce( (acc, word) => {
      acc[word] = acc[word] + 1 || 1;
      return acc;
    }, {})
```

I believe that each of these has time complexity *O*(*n*). Am I right?

Comment: *Why* would it increase the complexity? Is there any source claiming this?

Comment: Actually, time complexity is `O(s + w log w)` where `s` is the length of `string` and `w` the number of words in it.

Comment: There is no source claiming this. I am asking.

Comment: It is pretty much the same code. The difference is that you just save some intermediate result is a variable `wordArray`. This doesn't affect time complexity.

Comment: Sorting n elements is at least in O(n log(n)) but your comparison function is not in O(1) (perhaps on average?), so the overall runtime complexity is worse than O(n log(n)). Reducing the array is in O(n).

Comment: @Bergi Could you maybe go into more detail about O( s + w log w)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of different things:

1. Chaining doesn't impact time complexity in any way in this case. It is just a syntaxical difference.
2. I assume that n designs the number of words in the sentence you want to process. O(n) is an incorrect estimation for the time complexity. An efficient comparison sort usually takes O(nlog(n)) comparisons. Besides here, you are comparing strings, so the comparison is not made in constant time (with respect to the length of the strings). This doesn't change the fact that the complexity is O(nlog(n)) though since the length of the strings probably doesn't depend on n.
3. O(3n) = O(2n) = O(n) by definition, that's precisely what O means. Check out your [Landau notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Edit: following a commentary let me make the reasoning on the complexity clearer.

The `sort` function is called on the result of splitting a sentence on whitespaces, which comes to down to applying `sort` to a sequence of words.

I don't know how `sort` is implemented but it is very likely a comparison sort, meaning that it roughly does `O(n*log(n))` comparisons where n is the number of items being sorted: here the words of the sentence.

Now, we know that we will do `O(n*log(n))` string comparisons, which is not in constant time with respect to the length of the strings. String comparison takes at worst L operations, with L the length the minimum length of the two strings being compared. Let's now take L as the maximum length of the strings being sorted. From what has been said, we will do roughly `O(L*n*log(n))` operations to sort the array. Since there is no reason for L to depend on n, we have that `O(L*n*log(n)) = O(n*log(n))` operations for the time compexity.

Comment: OP implicitly expresses the time complexity with respect to the number of elements being sorted. If we strictly limit ourselves to that, then ideed sorting a sentence with no spaces would take O(1).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

> Does chaining increase time complexity?

No, intermediate variables do not change the time complexity, the algorithm is exactly the same.

> I believe that each of these has time complexity `O(n)`. Am I right?

No, although you haven't stated what `n` measures.

The complexity of your algorithm can be expressed as `O(s + (s/w) w log w)`, where `s` is the length of `string`, `w` the number of words in it and `s/w` the average word length (time needed for the string comparison); which simplifies to `O(s log w)`.

Comment: There's no difference between O(s + w log w) and O(s) in Big O notation unless you're describing every function individually. The entire algorithm itself remains O(w).

Comment: @EdmundoRodrigues You mean because the number of words is bounded by s? No, a string of length s could contain up to s/2 words. Thus replace w by s/2 and you end up with O(s log s).

Comment: @EdmundoRodrigues To combine the variables `s` and `w` into one, we have to make assumptions about how many words a string usually contains. If we don't allow spaces in our input, it's `O(s)`; if we say that words are constant-sized we'd get `O(w log w)`.

Comment: @Bergi Could you clarify why comparing words whose length is variable > O(1) but sorting w words whose total length is bounded by s is still in O(w log w)? (I feel that might be a point worth mentioning)

Comment: @le_m To simplify I assumed that comparing two words is `O(1)`. You're right, we'd need to multiply by `s/w` for each comparison, giving `O(s + s log w)` = `O(s log w)`

Comment: ```O(s+w*log(w))``` is wrong on many levels. First ```s``` should be the maximum length of the sorted strings because it is an upper bound on the time of string comparison. Second, it would then be ```O(s*w*log(w))``` because the string check is done on each comparison. Third, in would then simplify as ```O(w*log(w))```

Comment: @Anis `s` was assumed to be the length of `string`, and is linear to the execution time of the `string.split(" ")` operation. Regardless of the exact solution, my main point was that the formula does not solely depend on the number of words

Comment: Don't say "regardless of the exact solution" :( if there is a mistake you should correct it, there is no point leaving something wrong. Besides, I think you mix two things. 1) the time complexity of having to sort an array, and 2) the time complexity for a comparison. In the way OP asks the question it seems to me that he cares about the sorting part. Therefore the complexity with respect to that, if expressed with a big O notation, won't depend on the strings' length!! If you were to make a development to a lower order then yes it should appear. I'm not sure I'm making myself clear?

Comment: @Anis I think "*each of these*" in the question refers to the snippets containing the entire algorithm, not only the sorting part.

Comment: Yes indeed so the complexity is O(wlog(w)) for the entire algorithm. Thanks for the correction. O(slog(w)) = O(wlog(w)) when taking s equal to the length of the string. Because then ```s=w*average_word_length <= w*max_word_length``` and therefore ```O(slog(w))=O(w*max_word_length*log(w))=O(wlog(w))```.

Comment: @Anis You are assuming that there is a `max_word_length` - and while this assumption might be a useful thing for relevant cases, it is not an assumption we can make in general.

Comment: ```max_word_length``` is the maximum length of the words in the string. So it exists, and we can even say it is upper bounded by s ;)

Comment: @Anis There is no fixed maximum length for *all strings*, which we are considering here. Yes, `max_word_length` and `w` are bounded by `s`, but that means `O(s log w)` = `O(s log s)`, not = `O(w log w)` (which is just wrong)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139080/discussion-between-anis-and-bergi).

Comment: I don't care about maximum length for all strings. Whatever string with length s we take, it has a certain number of words w, and the complexity for sorting it is O(wlog(w)). ```max_word_length``` is an upper bound for the estimation, which is more than enough for O approximation and which allows me to make my demonstration by bounding the time complexity and showing that the worst case is still O(wlog(w)). But you are right to point out that O(slog(s)) = O(wlog(w)).

Comment: @Anis The complexity of sorting is `O(w log w)` only when we assume that a comparison runs in constant time, i.e. that the word length is bounded by a constant. But I don't think we should make that assumption.

Comment: Exercise to the reader: 1) show that s the function giving the length of the string is a linear function of the number of words w. 2) Use O definition to show that O(slog(s)) = O(wlog(w)) 3) conclude on the complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: @Anis Yes, except that 1) cannot be shown in general

Comment: Ok this is my final comment this discussion has taken long enough :). The difference of results is not the generality, it is just that we don't measure the same thing i.e with respect to what we compute the time complexity. Therefore the assumptions we can take are not the same. I reason the string being given, but I roughly agree with what you are trying to show. Anyway, good talk :)

Answer (score 0):

No, this doesn't make any difference (actually, maybe a very very very tiny, but very far to up the complexity from O(n) to O(n^2)).

And you're correct, your code is O(n log n), which n is the number of words from your string.

The sort method probably is implemented using quicksort, which is O(n log n) in the average case, and your reduce is a simple loop, O(n).